# Unexpected behavior of function

Tags: clojure

I write the following function to merge s2 into s1, and any element whose "id" value is same as any element in s1 will not be merged.

```
(defn into-unique-id 
  [s1, [x2 & xs2]]
  (if x2 (if (empty (filter (fn [x] (= (get x "id") (get x2 "id"))) s1)) (into-unique-id (conj s1 x2) xs2) (into-unique-id s1 xs2)) 
         s1))
```

I tried the following in REPL.

```
gridizela.core=> (def s1 [{"id" "1"} {"id" "2"}])
#'gridizela.core/s1
gridizela.core=> (into-unique-id s1 [{"id" "1"}])
[{"id" "1"} {"id" "2"} {"id" "1"}]
```

As you can see, the result was not as I expected, in which the last element should not be added.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to do a bit of refactoring in order to fix your problem, I am going to include each version of the code to show the steps needed to get the ideal result.

```
;; original
(defn into-unique-id 
  [s1, [x2 & xs2]]
  (if x2 (if (empty (filter (fn [x] (= (get x "id") (get x2 "id"))) s1)) (into-unique-id (conj s1 x2) xs2) (into-unique-id s1 xs2)) 
         s1))
```

The original code is unusually laid out, in a way that makes it hard for me to read, and hard for me to understand. So my first step was to apply normal indentation.

```
;; indentation
(defn into-unique-id-2
  [s1, [x2 & xs2]]
  (if x2
    (if (empty (filter (fn [x] (= (get x "id")
                                  (get x2 "id")))
                       s1))
      (into-unique-id (conj s1 x2) xs2)
      (into-unique-id s1 xs2)) 
    s1))
```

I still didn't quite get the code when I got to this point, but I saw some small changes that would make it easier to read. `cond` is almost always the thing you want instead of nested if conditionals. I use `,,` as whitespace to differentiate the result clauses from the condition clauses in `cond`.

```
;; simplification
(defn into-unique-id-3
  [s1, [x2 & xs2]]
  (cond (not x2)
        ,, s1
        (empty (filter (fn [x] (= (get x "id")
                                  (get x2 "id")))
                       s1))
        ,, (into-unique-id (conj s1 x2) xs2)
        :else
        (into-unique-id s1 xs2)))
```

At this point I finally saw the error: `(empty x)` will return truthy for any input that is not nil, even an empty collection. What we actually want here is the deceptively similarly named (but very different) `empty?` function.

```
;; fix -- empty is always truthy here
(defn into-unique-id-4
  [s1, [x2 & xs2]]
  (cond (not x2)
        ,, s1
        (empty? (filter (fn [x] (= (get x "id")
                                   (get x2 "id")))
                        s1))
        ,, (into-unique-id (conj s1 x2) xs2)
        :else
        (into-unique-id s1 xs2)))
```

next I saw that instead of `filter` / `empty?` we can use the built in `some`.

```
;; simplification -- we have idiomatic functions for this
(defn into-unique-id-5
  [s1, [x2 & xs2]]
  (cond (not x2)
        ,, s1
        (some (fn [x] (= (get x "id")
                         (get x2 "id")))
                        s1)
        ,, (into-unique-id s1 xs2)
        :else
        ,, (into-unique-id (conj s1 x2) xs2)))
```

Early on I noticed this was effectively a `reduce` done by hand, and so as a last step I'll show the function as a reduce.

```
;; structural simplification - we have idiomatic higher order functions
;; that we can use instead of recursion
(defn into-unique-id-6
  [s1, coll]
  (reduce 
   (fn [acc el]
     (if (some (fn [x]
                 (= (get x "id")
                    (get el "id")))
               acc)
       acc
       (conj acc el)))
   s1
   coll))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. I am still new to Clojure and I have learned a lot from the answer.